# Meteor MongoDB: How to aggregate date-range with computed end-date from collection field?

Tags: mongodb, date, aggregation-framework, computed-field

I'm using meteorhacks:aggregate package for Meteor, and I'm trying to find Events within a date-range between:

- now, minus one day.
- the end-date of the Event, plus two weeks.

Problem is, the end-date is stored in the Event document, in a field at `times.until`. The Event document looks like this:

```
// Event collection doc:
{
  _id: 'abc',
  times: {
    start: {
      dateTime: "ISODate("2017-03-07T00:00:00Z"),
      timeZone : "America/Chicago"
    },
    until: "20170307T000000Z"
  }
}
```

I able to aggregate to find dates in a range, but I can't figure out how to compute an end-date for the range based on the Event's `times.until` field.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
    'events.inProgress'() {
      const start = moment().utc().subtract(1, 'day').toDate();

      return Events.aggregate([
        {$match: {"times.start.dateTime": {$gt: start, $lt: end**(MUST COMPUTE end FROM DOC'S times.until PLUS 2 WEEKS)**}}},
      ]);
    }
  }
}
```

Also, note the format of the `times.until` field is `20170307T000000Z` (not sure the correct name of this format). This is not a valid format for a JavaScript `Date`, but moment.js handles this String no problem.  With access to the `times.until` field, I can do:

```
const end = moment(event.times.until).add(2, 'week').toDate();
```

This does give me the correct end-date of the range, but how can I grab the `times.until` field to compute the end-date while constructing the pipeline?

Comment: Would you be able to update the `times.until` to a valid date object before doing the aggregation? because it is almost impossible to construct a new date object correspondent with `times.until` in the pipeline.

Comment: @Khang Yes, I could wrap it before it is saved to mongo, using moment(until).toDate().

Comment: then that is what you should do, also the format of `until` field is this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ***[$add](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/add/)*** to add the milliseconds to get the date you want. Ofcourse this means the times.until 
 is mongo date type.

```
aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "times.start.dateTime": {
            $gt: start,
            $lt: {
                $add: ["$times.until", 14 * 24 * 60 * 60000]
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: I do not think this will work, it looks like the `until` field is a string

Comment: Yes that's the reason I mentioned in the answer it has be a date

Comment: Thanks @Khang, I misspoke, what I actually wanted was (`"times.until"` + 2 weeks) is greater than `now` - it's a two week extension on the event. I solved it using `$project` to create a computed date using the `$add` solution posted by @Veeram.  The computed date is then passed to `$match`, where I can compare it to `now`. There's prolly a more efficient way of doing this with `$redact`; I'll try to figure that out.